# ModelBuilder make no selection a valid selection?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, modelbuilder

Using ArcMap 10.3.1

What I am trying to achieve using ModelBuilder...

I want end users to select either 'roads', 'protected lines' or a combination of the two and then have the selected features merged into a new feature.

The problem I am having is if I select 'roads' but no 'protected lines' (or vice versa) the model assumes no selection means use the entire data set when I in fact want it to mean no selection/no data to merge.

I've tried incorporating the 'get count' tool but the result is the same as above (maybe I'm using it wrong?)

Image below of my model.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps use 2 get counts for each input, alternatively Little script that returns fidset length

Answer (score 3):

The Select tool copies features out to a new FeatureClass, so there is no *Selection* you have *Extracted* data instead.

If you want a selection to be honored by the count tool you need to be using the Select by Attribute or Select by Location tool to create the selections.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help all.

Solved my problem by converting my model to python and doing a count on selected feature rows and if the count resulted in more than 100 i.e. all features had been selected due to no cursor selection being made then delete the output.

## Get roads selected count and delete if more than 100

if int(arcpy.GetCount_management(Roads_Selected).getOutput(0)) > 100:
    arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management(Roads_Selected)